# Proposition reference in beamer

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing, theorems, presentations, newtheorem

I'm referring to [this conversation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237949/theorem-and-proposition-with-arbitrary-number-in-beamer) :

I want to reproduce the reference number of the proposition as in this example:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!15}

\newcommand{\propnumber}{} % initialize
\newtheorem*{prop}{Proposition \propnumber}
\newenvironment{propc}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\propnumber}{#1}%
   \begin{shaded}\begin{prop}}
  {\end{prop}\end{shaded}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{propc}{3.1}
    Proposition here.
\end{propc}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In my document, this is what I have:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{blue!15}

\newcommand{\propnumber}{} % initialize
\newtheorem*{prop}{Proposition \propnumber}
\newenvironment{propc}[1]
  {\renewcommand{\propnumber}{#1}%
   \begin{shaded}\begin{prop}}
  {\end{prop}\end{shaded}}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\useinnertheme{rounded}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Pessimistic Beliefs}
    \begin{propc}{3.1}
Prop here
    \end{propc}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I can't get why it is not working... I tried to remove every package and the themes, with no success...